# No module named 'openai_secret_manager'

Tags: python, pandas, openai-api, gpt-3

I asked **ChatGPT** about my CSV data, and ChatGPT answered:

"Here is an example of how you can read a CSV file using pandas, and then use the data to train or fine-tune **GPT-3** using the **OpenAI** API:"

```
import pandas as pd
import openai_secret_manager

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv")

# Get the OpenAI API key
secrets = openai_secret_manager.get_secrets("openai")
openai_api_key = secrets["api_key"]

# Use the data from the CSV file to train or fine-tune GPT-3
# (Assuming you have the OpenAI API key and the OpenAI Python library installed)
import openai
openai.api_key = openai_api_key
response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-002",
    prompt=(f"train on data from example.csv{df}"),
    max_tokens=2048,
    n = 1,
    stop=None,
    temperature=0.5,
)
print(response["choices"][0]["text"])
```

But, I got this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openai_secret_manager'`

Comment: Have you installed the openai package? https://github.com/openai/openai-python

Comment: Yes, I've installed openai packages, I've also tried to install "openai_secret_manager" using pip, but there isn't  @nofinator

Comment: GPT chat sometimes generate wrong code. Try to replace second line by import openai. And delete line started with secrets = . And here openai_api_key = past your API key as hardcode (if you don't know how to do it with environment variables).

Comment: Among other things, you can ask these questions to GPT chat. For example, if you write "openai_secret_manager is wrong package" he will apologize and say that it is not an official package created by the openAi community and optional.

Comment: *"GPT chat sometimes generate wrong code"* Ha! That's an understatement. ChatGPT is a chatbot. He knows nothing about programming and cannot handle complex algorithms. All he can do is generate sequences of words that look plausible. Of course ChatGPT cannot solve your problem. I suggest reading this blog post: [What is ChatGPT doing and why does it work?](https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2023/02/what-is-chatgpt-doing-and-why-does-it-work/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to use **openai_secret_manager**. I faced the same problem and deleted it and you need to generate & place an API from your account on OpenAI directly to the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import openai_secret_manager

# Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("example.csv")

# Use the data from the CSV file to train or fine-tune GPT-3
# (Assuming you have the OpenAI API key and the OpenAI Python library installed)
import openai
openai.api_key = openai_api_key
response = openai.Completion.create(
    engine="text-davinci-002",
    prompt=(f"train on data from example.csv{df}"),
    max_tokens=2048,
    n = 1,
    stop=None,
    temperature=0.5,
)
print(response["choices"][0]["text"])
```

[image]

Copy and paste the API and replace **openai_api_key** here

```
openai.api_key = "PLACE_YOUR_API_IN_HERE"
```

Comment: can you explain what does this line does? `f"train on data from example.csv{df}"` i consufed on `train on data from example.` and what is inside the csv file and format. thanks in advance

Comment: `example.csv` should have data that you have if you want to `fine-tune` `ChatGPT`. so basically, it is a way to make `ChatGPT` able to respond to people's questions based on the learning of the data that you would provide. For more info, you need to read from this [fine-tuning](https://beta.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning)

Comment: It seems that the answer's sample code still has the problematic import of "openai_secret_manager". I deleted that and just pasted in the literal string, and it worked:
openai.api_key = "my api key pasted from openai account page"

Comment: this answer is actually answering the question

Answer (score 1):

There's no `open_secret_manager` library.
There is an `openai-manager` library that helps using openAI API keys, especially if you are a team with many keys (https://pypi.org/project/openai-manager/).

It's not a good practice to use your personal API Key directly in the code, especially if you plan to commit the code in GIT. This would make your key visible to anyone that can exploit your paid access to openAI models.

The best practice is either store the key in a secret yml file and have it read in the code (and put the file in .gitignore to prevent it from commit) or store the key in a system environment variable and read it using:
openai.api_key = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']
There's explanation about how you do it in openai documentation here:
https://help.openai.com/en/articles/5112595-best-practices-for-api-key-safety